# Transition matrix

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, markov-chains

I have a directed graph $G_1$. I extract its transition matrix $T_1$.

Now I also have directed graph $G_2$, which is equal to $G_1$ with inverted edges.
If I get its transition matrix $T_2$, what is the relationship between $T_1$ and $T_2$?

What is the relationship between the adjancency matrices of $G_1$ and $G_2$?

Thanks for any hint, Mulone

Comment: Are you *asking* us if $T_2$ is the inverse of $T_1$, or are you stating it?

Comment: It won't be the inverse. Consider: if the digraph is a directed path $a \to b \to c$, its adjacency matrix isn't invertible; but the reversed digraph certainly does have an adjacency matrix. —— Why don't you take a look at some simple examples, like short directed paths, and see if anything jumps out at you?

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  $T_1$ has a $1$ in the $i,j$ location if there is a path from $V_i$ to $V_j$